# How do I disable jscript intellisense in VS 2008?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Javascript Initellisense keeps giving me errors in VS 2008 SP1. Whenever this happens, VS becomes unresponsive to the point where I can't get anything done. I would like to disable Javascript Intellisense temporarily to see if this is the issue. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Visual Studio menu select:

**Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> JScript**

Then uncheck `Auto List Members` and `Parameter Information`.